# Range of a function taking matrices to matrices contains a given set

Tags: multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

Consider $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ to be the space of all real $2\times 2$ matrices. Define $$S_r:=\{A\in M_2(\mathbb{R})\lvert \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|\leq r\}$$ for $r>0$. Now let $\Psi :M_2(\mathbb{R})\to M_2(\mathbb{R})$ be defined as $\Psi(X)=X^2+X$. Show there exists $r>0$ such that $S_r\subset \text{Range}\, \Psi$.

My attempt : I tried first to fix some $r>0$ and take any matrix with entries $r_{11}, r_{12}, r_{21}, r_{22}$ with $|r_{ij}|\leq r$ for each $i,j$. Then I tried to solve for $X$. But that breaks into a lot of cases and I believe I am going in a loop which will lead nowhere. My second idea was that in the range space we can define a metric on $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ by $\varrho(A,B)=\displaystyle \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}-b_{ij}|$. Then $S_r$ is simply the closed $r$-ball w.r.t this metric. But I still have no idea how to transform this into a proof. Can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use the inverse mapping theorem. Think of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ as $\mathbb{R}^4$. The map $\Psi$ can be written out in four coordinates, but even without doing this explicitly it should be clear that

1. $\Psi$ is continuously differentiable (all entries are polynomials)
2. $\Psi'(0)$ is the identity map, since $\Psi(X)=X+o(\|X\|)$ as $\|X\|\to0$.

The inverse function theorem says that $\Psi$ maps some neighborhood of $0$ bijectively onto some neighborhood of $\Psi(0)$ [which is also $0$], proving the claim.

(A neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is normally understood in the sense of $\sum x_i^2<\delta^2$, but you can show that such a neighborhood contains $S_r$ for small $r$.)